# Get Post ID with POST METAs in single MySQL query

Tags: mysql, wordpress, woocommerce, posts

From POSTS->ID, I want the first 12 IDs with post_type = 'product'
And with that ID association, I want to fetch all POST META.

I am using this MySQL query, but it is not working:

```
SELECT posts.ID, postmeta.meta_key, postmeta.meta_value FROM `wp_u8gwgg_posts` as posts

INNER JOIN wp_u8gwgg_postmeta as postmeta on posts.ID = postmeta.post_id

WHERE 

posts.`post_type` = 'product' AND 
posts.post_status = 'publish'

ORDER BY posts.ID
```

It is giving me redundant post_id in data.:

```
Post ID | Meta Key       | Meta Value
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
12      | _sku           | 18945236
12      | _price         | 1569.36
12      | _regular_price | 1496.20
```

I want result as:

```
Post ID | Meta Key                     | Meta Value
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
12      | _sku, _price, _regular_price | 18945236, 1569.36, 1496.20
```

If it is possible, do let me the solution.

**OR**

IF any better approach to this is also welcome.

Thanks

Comment: GROUP BY + GROUP_CONCAT()

Comment: I tried the same but it is giving me

`In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #1 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 'simpliav_wp.postmeta.post_id'; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT posts.ID, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(postmeta.meta_key ORDER BY posts.ID) meta_keys, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(postmeta.meta_value ORDER BY posts.ID) meta_values 
FROM wp_u8gwgg_posts as posts
INNER JOIN wp_u8gwgg_postmeta as postmeta on posts.ID = postmeta.post_id
WHERE posts.post_type = 'product' 
  AND posts.post_status = 'publish'
GROUP BY posts.ID
ORDER BY posts.ID
```